# CSS Media queries not working at specified max-width value (but instead starts to work at a lower value)

Tags: css, media-queries, width

So this has been baffling me for a while now. I have set a particular media query at `(max-width:480px)`. The problem is when my screen is slightly below `480px`, the CSS does not work. However, at around `370px`, it suddenly begins to work. Anyone out there who can help explain why this is happening to my code?

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap");

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 90vw;
}

.panel {
    background: no-repeat center center/cover;
    flex: 0.5;
    height: 80vh;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    transition: flex 0.3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.panel h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
    opacity: 0;
}

.container div:first-child {
    background-image: url(/assets/ales-krivec-4miBe6zg5r0-unsplash.jpg);
}

.container div:nth-child(2) {
    background-image: url(/assets/bailey-zindel-NRQV-hBF10M-unsplash.jpg);
}

.container div:nth-child(3) {
    background-image: url(/assets/ken-cheung-KonWFWUaAuk-unsplash.jpg);
}

.container div:nth-child(4) {
    background-image: url(/assets/luca-bravo-zAjdgNXsMeg-unsplash.jpg);
}

.container div:last-child {
    background-image: url(/assets/pietro-de-grandi-T7K4aEPoGGk-unsplash.jpg);
}

.panel.active {
    flex: 5;
}

.panel.active h3 {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .container {
        width: 100vw;
    }

    .panel:nth-of-type(4),
    .panel:nth-of-type(5) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="panel active">
            <h3>All you gotta do is call</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <h3>Winter</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <h3>Spring</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <h3>Summer</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <h3>Fall</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Thanks a lot for the guidance!

Comment: First I suggest you to give `.panel` a background color so people can help, second, for me it's working perfectly

Comment: the 4th and 5th children are exactly hidden at 480px and below, the same for `.container` width.

Comment: I have tested on the latest versions of (Chrome, FireFox and Edge )

Comment: That's so weird. I updated my Chrome and it now works fine. Thanks!!!